# Erro dependências gradle: all google.com.gms.libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Estou tentando adicionar um leitor de código de barras ao meu aplicativo e estou usando como base esse exemplo:
https://github.com/KingsMentor/MobileVisionBarcodeScanner
O erro aparece sempre que chego no passo 2, onde fala que preciso adicionar uma nova dependência no gradle:

```
dependencies {
        compile('com.github.KingsMentor:MobileVisionBarcodeScanner:v1.2') { transitive = true; }
}
```

Quando mando sincronizar, a linha

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
```

fica sublinhada de vermelho com a mensagem

> all google.com.gms.libraries must use the exact same version specification
>   (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 9.4.0,
>   7.8.0. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0 and
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0

e aparece a mensagem de erro no console do gradle:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@label value=() from AndroidManifest.xml:19:9-37      is also
> >     present at [com.github.KingsMentor:MobileVisionBarcodeScanner:v1.2]
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-41 value=(@string/app_name).     Suggestion:
> >     add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to  element at
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:16:5-369:19 to override.

Eu já tentei adicionar a linha `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0'` mas o erro continua

Comment: Tente usar: 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'

Comment: O sublinhado sumiu mas o erro no console continua